# Wordpress site not responsive cross browser

Tags: wordpress

I noticed my wordpress site is not very responsive and well styled in some browsers on mobile. I have tested it on PC and it is fine across all browsers but on mobile it is not displaying as styled especially on firefox and uc browser. Is there any plugin i can use for this on any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

try using a mobile theme plugin, there are many different ones that autodetect which device you are using an